# How to create Azure WebApp to an existing v1 VNet using ARM templates of PowerShell?

Tags: templates, azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

I have:

- A V1 VNet (classic) named VNET_DEV01_CLASSIC2.
- I have also a PowerShell Script that creates a WebApp (AppService) using ARM templates (Here you can see [template](http://pastebin.com/KCNtEHpJ)).

The new WebApp is created ok but then I need to manually connect it to V1 VNet

[image]

After connecting it, it works perfectly.

[image]

**How can automate this?** 
So far I tried two approaches unsucessfully:

**1) Updating ARM template to create it with the connection.**
I saw all the [azure-quickstart-templates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates) but did not found any WebApp that connect to VNet. I tried also to use [Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/) and deduct how would be the template resource, but unsuccessfully.

**2) After creating it, add some PowerShell commands to connect it to V1 VNet**
I cannot find any article to do it. [Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/) there is a comment from Ahmed IG that asks for the same and answered by compy@MSFT but the answer is not public...

I tried also to use [Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/) and follow PowerShell example but doesn't work. The error I am having is:

> New-AzureRmResource : The pipeline has been stopped. At
>   D:\cad\antstream\azure-devops\AzureManagementScripts\as-cms\kk.ps1:14
>   char:1
>   + New-AzureRmResource -ResourceName as-cms-dev01 -Location $ResourceLoc ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmResource], PipelineStoppedException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceCmdlet
>   New-AzureRmResource : {"Message":"The requested resource does not
>   support http method 'PUT'."} At
>   D:\cad\antstream\azure-devops\AzureManagementScripts\as-cms\kk.ps1:14
>   char:1
>   + New-AzureRmResource -ResourceName as-cms-dev01 -Location $ResourceLoc ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmResource], ErrorResponseMessageException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotAllowed,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceCmdlet

[image]

So my question is **How can automate this?**

Answer (score 2):

First you need an existing VNet with P2S configured as per my post at http://www.techdiction.com/2016/01/12/creating-a-point-to-site-vpn-connection-on-an-azure-resource-manager-virtual-network/

Then use the below PowerShell to connect the AppService to the VNet using P2S VPN:

```
$subscription_id = "<Subscription_ID>"
$NetworkName = "<Network_Name>"
$location = "<Region>"
$netrgname = "<Resource_Group_VNet_is_in>"
$AppServiceName = "<AppService_Name>"
 $props = @{
      "vnetResourceId" = "/subscriptions/$subscription_id/resourcegroups/$netrgname/providers/Microsoft.ClassicNetwork/virtualNetworks/$NetworkName";
      "certThumbprint"= "<Client_cert_thumbprint>";
      "certBlob"= "<Base64_Cert_Data>";
      "routes" = $null;
      }

New-AzureRMResource -ResourceName "$AppServiceName/$AppServiceName-to-$NetworkName" -Location $location  -ResourceGroupName MarcusWebsites -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/virtualNetworkConnections -PropertyObject $props -ApiVersion "2015-08-01" -force
```

You can configure custom routes if you require by modifying the routes property.

Marcus

Comment: How to do New-AzureRmResource using ARM templates?